# Add 1 for odd numbers on list Python

Tags: python

So this is my code:

```
numbers = []#1
for i in range(10):
  i += 1
  numbers.append(i)
print (numbers)

numbers2 = [n + 2 for n in numbers]#2
print (numbers2)

numbers3 = []#3
for x in numbers2:
  if (x % 2 == 1) :
    x += 1
    numbers3 = x
    print (numbers3)
```

I'm using Google Colab and run those codes on 3 separate code cells(hashtag numbers comment). The #1 program output is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`. And the #2 output is `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`. So at #3 cell I want program to add 1 on each odd numbers in `numbers2` list. The output I want is  `[4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 12, 12]`. But what I get is :

```
4
6
8
10
12
```

Also I'm trying to not use function(just for these codes). And `for` loop on #1 code I intend to do that.

Additional question : Is it possible to modify elements on list without `append` the result to another list(like #2 code)? Like just add 2 on each numbers on list

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll find this link very useful, especially the section on stepping through your code using a debugger. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
second_list = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
third_list = second_list
for i in range(len(second_list)):
  if (second_list[i] % 2 == 1):
    make_even = second_list[i] + 1
    third_list[i] = make_even
  else:
    third_list[i] = second_list[i]
print (third_list)
```

You'll have to tweak it for the Google Colab project you're doing, but the logic here should be right. Right now this answer works in regular Python 3.

Comment: Thank you so much. From your help I just realized about temporary list if I don't want to use append

Comment: @YoelRegen No worries. Knowing is growing!

Answer (score 0):

your third cell should look like this, you were close to the solution all you need to do is to add `x` values in numbers3 list

```py
numbers3 = []#3
for x in numbers2:
  if (x % 2 == 1) :
    x += 1
  numbers3.append(x)
print(numbers3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Both you and 61616 answers works but the output is only showing odd numbers(add 1) in a list

Answer (score -1):

In order to fill the list instead of just printing the value you must use the append function instead of =

```
numbers3 = x
#becomes
numbers3.append(x)
```

To get the list in the format you want, you also have to drop the append out of the if statement, and drop the print out of the for loop, like so:

```
numbers3 = []#3
for x in numbers2:
    if (x % 2 == 1) :
        x += 1
    numbers3.append(x) # Here
print (numbers3) # and here
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and answering my question about append

Answer (score -1):

```
any_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
even_list = list(map(lambda n: n | 1, any_list))
print(even_list)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for writing an answer. I formatted your code so it's at least readable. Feel free to [edit] your post to explain what you do and how this addresses the question. This will improve your chances of getting favorable feedback.